# How can I disable non-romanised characters and symbols in a text field?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I've a registration page and I've disabled the spacebar on the username field using the following code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[ 
    $(window).load(function(){
        $("#username").on("keydown", function (e) {
            return e.which !== 32;
        });
    });
//]]>  

</script>
```

However I've just spotted other characters that are causing issues for the system too. How can I disable any non-romanised characters or other symbols? Things such as this: á,#~!ČΨΩヲЖ

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question, but it may be frustrating for a user to type characters and not have them appear.  A better solution may be to display a warning next to the input box saying something like "only characters A-Z,a-z,0-9 are allowed."

Comment: A better solution is to use unicode everywhere.

Comment: Would you be able to help me with a code for that too? I'm afraid I wouldn't know where to begin with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a charCode range and handpick what you need:

```
$("#username").on("keydown", function (e) {
    var charcode = e.which;
    if ( (charcode === 8) || // Backspace
        (charcode >= 48 && charcode <= 57) || // 0 - 9
        (charcode >= 65 && charcode <= 90) || // a - z
        (charcode >= 97 && charcode <= 122)) { // A - Z
        console.log(charcode)
    } else {
        e.preventDefault()
        return
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CC6BW/3/

Don't forget to preventDefault for what you do not need

The Latin Chart is here:
http://www.idautomation.com/product-support/ascii-chart-char-set.html

Comment: Thanks perfect, thank you! Any ideas how to allow the backspace for that too? So that users can edit a mistake if they type one?

Comment: This doesn't allow for arrow keys (going back and forth to edit something) but it allows for numberpad symbols "/*+-."

Comment: Everything can be put off or on based on the charcode. Just set it up as it fits you

Answer (score 1):

You could solve this problem with either regular expressions.

If you just want to include character sets A-Z, a-z, and 0-9 (with no accents), then you can use the following regex to identify whether a character is in those sets:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]/.test(e)
```

Better yet, rather than interfering with the user's key entries (which might be frustrating) you could put a warning next to the input when an invalid character is entered.  Let's say you had a `<span id="warning"></span>` next to `<input id="username">`:

```
$("#username").on("keydown", function (e) {
    if ( !( /^[a-zA-Z0-9]/.test(e) ) ) {
        $("#warning").text("Only values from a-z, A-Z, and 0-9 are valid");
    }
});
```